# Unable to run a cakephp project in wampserver?

Tags: php, cakephp, wampserver

I have downloaded a CakePHP project from live server, which is working fine on live server, but when I tried to run it on local wamp server, then it is not working, neither it shows any error nor any kind of warning, just showing plain text.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two links may help you:

- [book.cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html)
- [bakery.cakephp.org](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/BBBThunda/2010/02/25/troubleshooting-cakephp-installation-issues-related-to-apache-2-mod_rewrite-for-beginners)

Answer (score 2):

Please check your Apache rewrite_module is on. It should be on localhost. Hope the website will run after this. Also check for the configuration pages such as .htaccess & config page